# Preserve Apple Watch fitness data when resetting and syncing to a new iPhone

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, apple-watch

I just got a new iPhone and I have an existing watch.  There were some pairing problems, so I was prepared to erase my Apple Watch and do the pairing again - no problem - I’ve done it before.
The only thing is that by the time I’d figured out it wasn’t working, I’d done a 1000 calorie workout.  If I have to lose that data I will, but I’d prefer not to.  Is there any way I can connect without erasing or save the fitness data first?

Comment: The data should be saved to the Health app, not the Watch.  Have you verified the workout is there?

Comment: @fsb - it’s not there on my phone.  The data doesn’t show up in fitness or health.  But it does on my watch